# Event is triggered only once when applied to multiple elements

Tags: javascript, html, events, dom-events, addeventlistener

I am creating a form dynamically with plain JS. Whenever the last input field receives an input, another empty one should be created. On the other hand the last field should be removed when the one before the last becomes empty, too.

HTML (before user input):

```
<div id="eventList" class="gap">
        <input id="event1" class="text bold eventBox" type="text" name="event1" placeholder="Ereignis 1" /> <br>
</div>
```

Javascript (implemented afterwards; in excerpts):

```
function addBox() {
    
    var boxes = document.getElementsByClassName("eventBox");
    
    var id = +getMaxID(boxes, "event") + +1;           // ID of input being created
    
    var list = document.getElementById("eventList");
    
    list.innerHTML = list.innerHTML + '<input id="event'+ id +'" class="text bold eventBox" type="text" name="event'+ id +'" placeholder="Ereignis '+ id +'" /> <br>';
    
    document.getElementById("event" + id).addEventListener("input", resizeEventList);
    
}

function delBox() {
            
    loadTexts();                // save current inputs
    
    var list = document.getElementById("eventList");
    
    document.getElementById("eventList").innerHTML = '';
    
    var id = 1;
    
    for (var i = 1; i < eventTexts.length; i++) {
        
        if (eventTexts[i].length > 0) {
            
            /* recreate box with its former input (if not empty) */
            
            document.getElementById("eventList").innerHTML = document.getElementById("eventList").innerHTML + '<input id="event'+ id +'" class="text bold eventBox" type="text" name="event'+ id +'" placeholder="Ereignis '+ id +'" value="' + eventTexts[i] + '"/> <br>';
            document.getElementById("event" + id).addEventListener("input", resizeEventList);
            
            id++;
            
        }
        
    }
    
    /* add new last empty input */
    
    document.getElementById("eventList").innerHTML = document.getElementById("eventList").innerHTML + '<input id="event'+ id +'" class="text bold eventBox" type="text" name="event'+ id +'" placeholder="Ereignis '+ id +'" value=""/> <br>';
    document.getElementById("event" + id).addEventListener("input", resizeEventList);
    
}

function resizeEventList(e) {
    
    if (typeof e != 'undefined') {
        
        var boxes = document.getElementsByClassName("eventBox");
        
        if (e.target.id == "event"+getMaxID(boxes, "event") && e.type == 'input') {
            
            /* input into last available box -> add an empty box */
            
                loadTexts();                // save current inputs

                senderID = e.target.id;     // remember ID of triggering element for resetting focus afterwards

                addBox();                   // add another box
            
                writeTexts();               // write former inputs back into boxes
            
                document.getElementById(senderID).focus();     // reset focus
            
        } else if (e.target.value.length == 0 && getID(e.target, "event") < getMaxID(boxes, "event")) {
            
            /* box before last box empty -> delete last empty box */

                senderID = e.target.id;     // remember ID of triggering element for resetting focus afterwards

                delBox();                   // delete all boxes and create X new boxes
            
                document.getElementById(senderID).focus();     // reset focus
            
        }
        
    }
    
}

var eventTexts = new Array();
var senderID;
document.getElementById("event1").addEventListener("input", resizeEventList);
```

The problem now: When I apply all Event Listeners only to the input named "event1", the code works as expected - adding an input when typing, removing one when empty, just for event1 only. When I apply the Event Listeners also to the dynamically created inputs (as it should be and is written in the code above), the input event is triggered only once at the first input ever made, including event1. All following inputs are not recorded anymore.

Does anybody have a solution?

--- FULL CODE --------------------

```
<form id="planForm" class="top-margin" method="post" action="new.php?action=add">

    <div>
        <input class="text head bold" type="date" name="date" placeholder="Datum" value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d", time());?>" required /> <br>

        <div id="eventList" class="gap">

            <input id="event1" class="text bold eventBox" type="text" name="event1" placeholder="Ereignis 1" /> <br>

        </div>
    </div >

<input type="button" value="Speichern" onclick="save();" /  >

</form>

<script>

    function getID(elm, type) {
        if (typeof elm != 'undefined') {
            return elm.id.replace(type, "");
        } else {
            return "";
        }
    }

    function getMaxID(list, type) {

        currID = 0;
        max = 0;

        if (list != null && list.length > 0 && type != null) {
            for (var i=0; i < list.length; i++) {
                currID = getID(list[i], type);
                if ( currID > max ) {
                    max = currID;
                }
            }
        }

        return max;

    }

    function addBox() {

        var boxes = document.getElementsByClassName("eventBox");

        var id = +getMaxID(boxes, "event") + +1;           // ID of input being created

        var list = document.getElementById("eventList");

        list.innerHTML = list.innerHTML + '<input id="event'+ id +'" class="text bold eventBox" type="text" name="event'+ id +'" placeholder="Ereignis '+ id +'" /> <br>';

        document.getElementById("event" + id).addEventListener("input", resizeEventList);

        console.log(document.getElementById("event" + id));

    }

    function delBox() {

        loadTexts();                // save current inputs

        var list = document.getElementById("eventList");

        document.getElementById("eventList").innerHTML = '';

        var id = 1;

        for (var i = 1; i < eventTexts.length; i++) {

            if (eventTexts[i].length > 0) {

                /* recreate box with its former input (if not empty) */

                document.getElementById("eventList").innerHTML = document.getElementById("eventList").innerHTML + '<input id="event'+ id +'" class="text bold eventBox" type="text" name="event'+ id +'" placeholder="Ereignis '+ id +'" value="' + eventTexts[i] + '"/> <br>';
                document.getElementById("event" + id).addEventListener("input", resizeEventList);

                id++;

            }

        }

        /* add new last empty input */

        document.getElementById("eventList").innerHTML = document.getElementById("eventList").innerHTML + '<input id="event'+ id +'" class="text bold eventBox" type="text" name="event'+ id +'" placeholder="Ereignis '+ id +'" value=""/> <br>';
        document.getElementById("event" + id).addEventListener("input", resizeEventList);

    }

    function resizeEventList(e) {

        if (typeof e != 'undefined') {

            var boxes = document.getElementsByClassName("eventBox");

            if (e.target.id == "event"+getMaxID(boxes, "event") && e.type == 'input') {

                /* input into last available box -> add an empty box */

                    loadTexts();                // save current inputs

                    senderID = e.target.id;     // remember ID of triggering element for resetting focus afterwards

                    addBox();                   // add another box

                    writeTexts();               // write former inputs back into boxes

                    document.getElementById(senderID).focus();     // reset focus

            } else if (e.target.value.length == 0 && getID(e.target, "event") < getMaxID(boxes, "event")) {

                /* box before last box empty -> delete last empty box */

                    senderID = e.target.id;     // remember ID of triggering element for resetting focus afterwards

                    delBox();                   // delete all boxes and create X new boxes

                    document.getElementById(senderID).focus();     // reset focus

            }

        }

    }

    function loadTexts() {
        var boxes = document.getElementsByClassName("eventBox");

        for (var i=0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
            eventTexts[getID(document.getElementById(boxes[i].id), "event")] = boxes[i].value;
        }
    }

    function writeTexts() {
        var boxes = document.getElementsByClassName("eventBox");

        for (var i=0; i < boxes.length-1; i++) {
            document.getElementById(boxes[i].id).value = eventTexts[getID(boxes[i], "event")];
        }
    }

    var eventTexts = new Array();
    var senderID;
    document.getElementById("event1").addEventListener("input", resizeEventList);

</script>
```

Comment: have you logged out that you are actually getting the element on the page before adding the listener?

Comment: Yes, I get the correct IDs, but only after the first input. Further inputs don't trigger the event at all

Comment: did you see if this is returning the element ?  document.getElementById("event" + id)

Comment: Yep, it gets returned. The weird thing: The dynamically added listeners as well as the listener for event1 work properly, but only once. After that, none of them seems to fire the event anymore.

Comment: It would help if you posted a working example. (including `resizeEventList()` etc.)

Comment: Okay, wanted to keep it as short as possible (resizeEventList is included). Will add the rest now.

Comment: The issue could be with using innerHTML for appending new inputs. See this answer for a similar issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28441798/javascript-addeventlistener-fires-only-once

Comment: @RajeshP Yes, that's it! Thanks, gonna remind this rule now... insertAdjacentHTML works perfectly. Without changing the actual code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For everybody who wants to know the solution:

use "insertAdjacentHTML" instead of "innerHTML" to create elements dynamically. Thanks to RajeshP for giving a link to this helpful answer: [Javascript AddEventListener Fires only once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28441798/javascript-addeventlistener-fires-only-once)

Comment: Thank you, changing 'innerHTML' to 'insertAdjacentHTML' solved a lot many problems for me.