# How to include a class inside javascript innerHTML method?

Tags: javascript, css

I'm working on a dynamic form in which when I select a particular option from drop down list, a new field appears. My problem is that it is not stylized as it is not picking the class. Here is my code.

```
document.getElementById('div2').innerHTML = '<select class="selectmenu"> <option selected="selected">Select Clinic</option> <option value="Clinic1">Clinic1</option> <option value="Clinic2">Clinic2</option> </select>';
```

the "selectmenu" class is not loading.

Comment: Are you sure the problem is here? It looks quite fine. Does the class not appear when inspecting in the console, or is there any other error?

Comment: Looks fine, have a play with https://jsfiddle.net/cr8caxoj/ and see if there is a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it looks fine, but I recently had some problems using innerHTML directly, too. What about trying this:

```
document.getElementById("div2").innerHTML = "";
document.getElementById("div2").insertAdjacentHTML('<select class="selectmenu"> <option selected="selected">Select Clinic</option> <option value="Clinic1">Clinic1</option> <option value="Clinic2">Clinic2</option> </select>');
```

Have a look at my posts' answer: [Event is triggered only once when applied to multiple elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45168877/event-is-triggered-only-once-when-applied-to-multiple-elements)

Maybe it's just weird happening again...

Comment: But [`Element#insertAdjacentHTML` is a function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML).